# hide/show div based on url doesn't work at the first load of the multi html pages

Tags: javascript

I already check here on stackoverlow and I didn't find what I need.

I'm trying to hide and show some DIV based on the #url and It's almost done but the first time you enter in that html page (it's a three different page website) the function doesn't work.

here the function I use:

```
/***************
HIDE BANDS DEPENDING ON THE URL
***************/

// Bind the event.
window.onhashchange = updatebands;


function updatebands() {

if (location.href.match(/projectos.html#bandOne/)){
  $('#bandOne').css("display", "block");
  $('#bandTwo').css("display", "none");
  $('#bandThree').css("display", "none");
} 
if (location.href.match(/projectos.html#bandTwo/)){
  $('#bandOne').css("display", "none");
  $('#bandTwo').css("display", "block");
  $('#bandThree').css("display", "none");
} 
if (location.href.match(/projectos.html#bandThree/)){
  $('#bandOne').css("display", "none");
  $('#bandTwo').css("display", "none");
  $('#bandThree').css("display", "block");
}
};
```

I've tried also to complement the CSS file with the code below but when enter for the first time I have the same problem (this time it all hides instead of all shown)

```
.section {
  display: none;
}
```

I think it's because I load the html and the function doesn't work, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you should use `window.location.hash` to check the *hash* part of the url, but what you should really use is some **router** script

Comment: I recommend this tiny router: https://github.com/krasimir/navigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter the page for the first time the `window.onhashchange` isn't getting triggered, so nothing there will run.
If you want - you can also use the `window.onload` function (or better use the `window.addEventListener` to make sure you don't override anything and no script will override your function):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    updatebands()
});
```

Note that you still need to keep the `hashchange` event:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(event) {
    updatebands()
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've solved adding your function before mine.
If I use just your function it works when you enter but when you change between band not. you need the haschange function

Comment: I didn't say to remove the `onhashchange`, just to **add** the `load` :)

Comment: I thought the load function replace also the other, my misunderstanding :)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

### Using only CSS [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class:

```css
p{ display:none; } /*- hide all paragraphs initially */
:target{ display:block; } /* only shows the one which the "hash" is pointing at */
```

```html
<ol>
 <li><a href="#p1">Show part 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#p2">Show part 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#p3">Show part 3</a></li>
</ol>

<p id="p1">Part 1</p>
<p id="p2">Part 2 is this one</p>
<p id="p3">This is part 3</p>
```

when the URL contains the hash part which matches an `id` id a paragraph, only that paragraph will be displayed. no javascript used.

Comment: very interesting solution :) but it works also on a multi-page website?

Comment: @Sebastiano - yes why wouldn't it? Try it :)